# How to handle exception from timer in blazor?

Tags: c#, multithreading, blazor, blazor-server-side

How to i correclty handle an exception thrown in another Thread (from Timer) in Blazor Server-Side?

Ideally i want the error to bubbly like all the other exceptions and trigger the yellow error bar.

[image]

Unfortunatly the exception terminates the whole application. I can put an try catch around the methode call, but would prefere to handle this more globally.

This is the code i run, inside the Elapsed-Handler (HandleSearchTimerElapsed) an Exception is thrown. This terminates the application, which i obviosly dont want.

```
@page "/"

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ResetDelayTimer">Throw Error with Timer</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => throw new Exception("Simple Error"))">Simple Error without Timer (shows yellow error bar)</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;
    private System.Timers.Timer? _delayTimer;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _delayTimer = new(200) { AutoReset = false, };

        _delayTimer.Elapsed += HandleSearchTimerElapsed;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private async void HandleSearchTimerElapsed(object? sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            await InvokeAsync(() => throw new Exception("From InvokeAsync in Timer"));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // How to throw this "normally" ? i want to see the yellow exception bar
            throw;  // This terminates the Application
        }
    }

    private void ResetDelayTimer()
    {
        _delayTimer!.Stop();
        _delayTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

Can i trigger the "normal" exception handler from blazor?

Comment: This is inherent to `async void` methods. They "run unobserved", nobody there to catch the error.  But that "yellow error bar" isn't a very desirable feature. You can handle it better now, just throw out the `throw;`.

Comment: mmh yes the yellow error bar is not the best, but this was more like the basic demo. the new ErrorBoundries also dont work. the async void is due to the event handler. i know i can build my own error handling here, but i would love to trigger the "normal" error pipeline so that i dont have do build it multiple times and need to wrap every single timer in my blazor code with a seperate try catch. can i "throw the exeption back" to the origin compnent?